# JSP tag which shortens iffing null attributes

Tags: jsp, if-statement, jsp-tags

I'm looking for a cleaner way to write such jsp snippet:

```
<a href="${model.link}" class="button"<c:if test="${not empty model.title"> title="${model.title}"</c:if>>
```

This code is hard to read. The problem is, that there shouldn't be generated empty `title=""` tag attribute, so this part have to be iffed.

I've found `<c:out>` tag with it's default value attribute, however:

```
<c:out value='title="${model.title}"' default=""/>
```

won't work fine, cause value won't be null ever (since it is safe String concat).

Is there any way to write such easy stuff shorter, cleaner, better?

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:if test = "${not empty model.title}">
<c:set var = "title" value = "title = '${model.title}'"/>
</c:if>
<a href="${model.link}" class="button" ${title}>
```

You could also do a custom taglib, so you'd end up with something like this:

```
<my:link class = "button" model = "${model}">...</my:link>
```

Since servlet spec somthing-rather you could implement the taglib as a jsp-snippet or you could go all the way using Java.

Comment: Upvote for your effort, however this isn't cleaner in any way.

Comment: Depends, I personally don't like to see <c:if inside other tags.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is as such;

```
<a href="${model.link}" class="button"<% if (model.title != null) { %> title="${model.title}"<% } %>>
```

a bit shorter than your first example, but still a bit too cluttering.

Bare in mind however, that your title still needs to be sanitized, since its encapsulated in a html tag.

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(mode.title)
```

Comment: Upvote for your effort, however this isn't cleaner in any way. Thanks for tip of escaping, but I'm doing it actually in internal class implementation.